How to capture the 'groupclick' event of an Ext JS grid panel when first column is locked?
I have a grid panel in ext.js 7.2.
I have an ext js grouped grid where the first column is locked. I want to do add custom logic when the group header is clicked. However, when I click on the group header, the groupclick event is not called.
Group expand and group collapse event are triggered.
Ext.define('MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    features: [{
        ftype: 'grouping'
    }],
    listeners: 
        {
            groupexpand: function(view, node, group) {
                console.log('Group expanded');
            },
            groupcollapse: function(view, node, group) {
                console.log('Group collapsed');
            },
            groupclick: function (view, node, group) {
                console.log('Group click');
            }
        },
    columns: [{
        text: 'Task',
        flex: 1,
        tdCls: 'task',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'description',
        locked:true
    }, 
}


Can you create a Sencha Fiddle to demonstrate your issue? I tried and it is triggered for me.

groupclick is not triggered when the first column is locked. I have updated my question.

Try using groupclick listener inside "lockedGridConfig" like below example,
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    width: 200,
    height: 240,
    renderTo: document.body,

    lockedGridConfig: {
        listeners: {
            groupclick: function() {
                alert(1);
            }
        }
    },
    normalGridConfig: {
        listeners: {
            groupclick: function() {
                alert(1);
            }
        }
    },
    features: [{
        groupHeaderTpl: 'Subject: {name}',
        ftype: 'groupingsummary'
    }],
    store: {

        groupField: 'subject',
        data: [{
            student: 'Student 1',
            subject: 'Math',
            mark: 84
        }, {
            student: 'Student 1',
            subject: 'Science',
            mark: 72
        }, {
            student: 'Student 2',
            subject: 'Math',
            mark: 96
        }, {
            student: 'Student 2',
            subject: 'Science',
            mark: 68
        }]
    },
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'student',
        text: 'Name',
        locked: true,
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'mark',
        text: 'Mark',
        summaryType: 'average'
    }]
});

